# Extend Eclipse XML Editor's Design View to display certain Content

Tags: eclipse, xml-editor, design-view

As soon as a schema is attached to an XML document the design view of Eclipse XML editor displays the possible children of a node on the right-hands side.
I'm interested in changing this when an element has a certain attribute to display the attributes content instead. 
Is it possible to extend Eclipses XML editor to implement this behaviour?
At the moment I can only hide certain nodes, but I can't find the method to override for the displayed content per node.
Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: I found a way to display the information I want in my custom XML editors design view.
It requires an own implementation of XMLTableTreeContentProvider. The method getColumnText(Object object, int column) is responsible for the text being displayed both on the left (column 0) and the right side (column 1) in the design view.
In this method the result of the call to the super method may be easily overridden / changed / adapted.